# Scala - REPL - non-ASCII characters

Tags: java, scala, read-eval-print-loop

This question is about the Scala REPL.

If I enter a non-ASCII char e.g. π, I only see ? in the REPL console.
So it does not display the non-ASCII chars properly.

I tried the solutions suggested here but
they don't work for me for some reason.

http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/5904

I am using Windows 7 and Java 8.

I am putting also a Java tag here only because it's related to the `-Dfile.encoding` JVM option.

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me (Linux).  Do these chars show cleanly for you in other terminal (e.g. shell) i/o?

Comment: @jwvh Linux is a bit different than Windows :) No, they don't.

Comment: Ah, my point exactly.  It doesn't sound like a REPL issue.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks, well, I got your point the 1st time but that doesn't really solve the problem in full.

Comment: @jwvh Now I fixed the Windows shell, it can display e.g. π, but the Scala REPL/shell still does not display it properly. Now it's a problem with the REPL.

Comment: Cool.  Glad we got that clarified.